# Could not find plugin 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, build

'm trying to build an Android project using Gradle, but I keep getting the error message:

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.4.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

I'm using Gradle version 7.0.2 and I've added the following to my build.gradle file:

plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
...
}

I've also tried using version 7.1.4, but I get the same error. Can anyone help me figure out why I can't find the com.android.application plugin in Gradle? Thanks!

I tried building an Android project using Gradle in Android Studio. I expected the build process to complete successfully without any errors. However, I encountered an error message that stated the plugin for com.android.application version 7.4.1 could not be found in any of the available sources. I tried adding the necessary plugin to the build.gradle file, but the error persisted. I also tried running a clean build, but it did not resolve the issue. I am now seeking assistance on how to resolve this issue.